# Find the constant value in the Probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a Random Variable N that has a pmf:

$$p(N=k)=C(k+1)(n-k+1), \text{ for } k=0,1,2,..., n \text{ and } C \text{ is a constant }$$

I am asked to find (a) the constant value $C$, (b) the CDF and (c) the Mean.

In attempting part (a) I found that the pmf is symmetrical and I used that fact to simplify the $\sum p(k)$ into a more manageable one. However it is very algebra heavy and I feel that there is a easier method in completing part (a) and the other parts. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any idea what $\sum_{k = 0}^n \mathbb{P}(N = k)$ should be?

Comment: Yes, that equals 1. Sorry that I didn't make it clear that I knew that.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the (k+1) term from the summation like that? I thought that since it is dependent on k you can not do that.

Comment: I removed the comment, was a typo. See the answer now :)

Comment: Ah thanks! I guess from there you would use the formulas for summation of k and k^2 consecutive numbers and simplify. Thanks once again :)

Comment: No problem. If it turns out that the hint was helpful and you managed to solve the problem, then you can possibly come back and accept the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you continue from the following?

\begin{align}
1 &= \sum_{k = 0}^n \mathbb{P}(N = k) = \sum_{k = 0}^n C (k + 1) (n - k + 1) = C \sum_{k = 0}^n (k + 1)(n - k + 1) \\
&= C \sum_{k = 0}^n (kn -k^2 +k +n - k + 1) = C \sum_{k = 0}^n (kn -k^2 +n + 1) \\
&= C \Bigl( \sum_{k = 0}^n k(n-k) + \sum_{k = 0}^n (n + 1) \Bigr) \\
&= C \Bigl( \sum_{k = 0}^n k(n-k) + n(n + 1) \Bigr).
\end{align}